# schema validation with trax

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xml-validation

If I want to apply schema validation to XML read when apply XSLT with the Transformer interface, do I need to first build a DOM with a DOMSource with validation enabled, or is there some way to persuade it to do this with a StreamSource?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot think of a way using a StreamSource, but you should be able to construct a validating SAXParser, obtain an XMLReader from it and use that as input to a SAXSource. At least this prevents a tree being built before the transformation. However, the transformation might very well construct a tree, anyways.